# Inheriting only some of the parameters of the parent's constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, inheritance

I have the following classes, and i only want that the inherited class B to have only some of the parameters of parent class A

```
class A{
private:
   int quantity;
   int price;
protected:
   char *name;
   char *category;
public:
  A(int quantity, int price, char *name, char* category)
{ } // CONSTRUCTOR 

};


class B: public A
{
private:
   char *location;
public:
   B(int quantity, int price, char *name, char* category, char *location) :A(quantity, price,name, category)
};
```

What i want to do is that making class B inherit only name, and category from A, like this:

```
 B(char *name, char* category, char *location) :A(name, category)
```

but it doesn't work, i thought that making those attributes private will solve my problem, but it didn't. Is there a way to do this, or i have to make another class with the required attributes?

Comment: the constructor and destructor are not inheritible and private data also.

Comment: Give `A` another constructor with just two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: You can make another constructor for A that takes only those two parameters:

```
A(char *name, char* category) {...} 
...
B(char *name, char* category, char *location) :A(name, category) {...}
```

Solution 2: You can keep only one constructor for `A` (the same one you made) but with *default values* for `quantity` and `price`:

```
A(char *name, char* category, int quantity = 0, int price = 0) {...}
// Notice that the parameters that have default values must come at
// the end of the param list

...
    B(char *name, char* category, char *location) :A(name, category) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to this and I didn't know you can make many constructors in a class.